# php count function not showing the right count on mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have got data from mysql_fetch_assoc stored in to an array using this command

```
if(mysql_num_rows($data) > 1){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
                    $ndata[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $ndata = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
            }
```

Now when I use count on `$ndata`, it retuns 1; although it is empty.

When I run mysql_num_rows on the returned data it retuns 0 rows. But when I convert the data to $ndata and then run count on that it returns 1. I want it to return the number of rows.

Thanks

Can someone please explain why is there a problem and how to fix it?

Comment: With this code you can get number of rows with count only when numb rows > 1.

Comment: What is this code for? Ir;s quite hard to guess and give proper answer.

Comment: store the data in an array from a mysql result.

Comment: you're storing it in 2 kinds of arrays. And most likely wrong way. are you sure you need separate array for the single row? it will require separate code to process it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong: you don't test for the case that `mysql_num_rows($data) == 0`. If this is the case, your code executes the same path as when the number of rows is 1 (`$ndata = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);`). But there are no more rows to return (there are no rows at all), so `mysql_fetch_assoc` [returns `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). And `count(false)` returns `1`, because that's how `count` works.

Do it this way:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
if($rows == 0) {
    return null;
}
else if($rows == 1){
    $ndata = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
        $ndata[] = $row;
    }
}
```

You can either return `null` or `array()` in the first `if` branch; these are the only two values for which `count` returns 0.

Comment: The logic is not wrong. if num_rows < 1 then why is count not returning 0.

Comment: @user658911: You end up doing `count(false)`, which returns `1`. Follow the links I give (especially the documentation for `count`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Comment: @user658911: mysql_num_rows() returns false if the number of rows is equal to 0.  Count(false) will return 1. Count(null) will return 0.

Comment: Downvoter: I would appreciate it if you helped me improve the answer.

Comment: I'd add my -1. this code shouldn't exist. If 1 row were returned when more expected, it will mess further execution.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I seriously doubt that, as the OP's code already does this and I think we can safely assume it's working so far. But you can downvote all you like of course.

Comment: LOL such assumption makes no sense. "working so far" being source of all problems.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: You should know by now that I won't argue with you. Have a nice day.

Comment: This is public site and I am arguing not with particular person but more likely to spread my brilliant knowledge in general. But you're amusing me, so let me teach you a lesson. Imagine we have a poor guy who doesn't sanitize his SQL data (there are plenty of them here). Their code is indeed **working so far.** Would you still insist to leave his code intact?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Don't spread your brilliant knowledge too far though. If you teach us too much we might stop amusing you.

Comment: Not until I see sensible answers on SO. Honestly, if it wasn't me pointing to that issue, you'd agree.

Comment: thanks Jon, i appreciate your answer and why does @Col. Shrapnel have to interfere and disturb other people while he could give an answer himself if he knew what to do and if he was willing to help. No need to answer this question @Col. Shrapnel. I am gonna give you an upvote and accept your answer. Thanks once again, Jon.

Comment: @user658911 sure I know what to do so I wrote my answer. If you didn't notice :)

Answer (score 2):

I think `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is returning false (see [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)) and `count(false)` returns 1.

Comment: what is count(NULL) equal to?

Comment: there questions going to be infinite... ;)

Comment: @user658911 I think it'd be easier to ask PHP rather than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
      $ndata[] = $row;
}
if(count($ndata) == 1) $ndata = $ndata[0];
```

Runing query that returns 1 row and

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online LIMIT 1");
print_r($ndata);
```

Result

```
Array ( [timestamp] => 1301826108 [ip] => 213.186.122.2)
```

Runing query with multiple rows...

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online");
print_r($ndata);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1301848228
            [ip] => 67.195.112.29
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1301826108
            [ip] => 213.186.122.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1301825465
            [ip] => 77.88.28.246
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1301763579
            [ip] => 69.171.224.251
        )

)
```

Comment: you can't rely on the number of rows returned. there can be merely 1 row when your code expect nested array

Comment: I still can't see what is wrong, $ndata[0] is first/only row, instead of $ndata[0]["id"] you then access it by $ndata["id"], which only works if one row is returned. This loop is fetching data into array (not mysql array).

Comment: there is not such thing like "mysql array". this code will return 2 kinds of arrays. So, you will need 2 different codes to handle it. But you cannot know which one to use.

Comment: I meant you can't fetch assoc of an array like you did in your code.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I updated my answer, tested the code and it is working as expected.

Comment: I know that it works. But there would be further code to handle these different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I finally got what you need (However, question remains extremely vague and it's hard to tell for sure). But anyway.

```
$ndata = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
  $ndata[] = $row;
}
```

Now you would get desired result from `count($ndata)`. It will return 0 for no rows, 1 for 1 row and whatever number if more rows returned. Bingo!

But if you're still planning to get different kinds of arrays, I should warn you against doing it this way.
Always state explicitly what kind of result you want to get:

```
$ndata = array();
if ($type=="row"){
  $ndata = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
} elseif ($type=="array"){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
    $ndata[] = $row;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that was also my first conclusion, It is 2D array instead of 1D (if there is only one row).

Comment: @Pekka that's long story, LOL. in fact it's coming from the preface.

Comment: @Col I'm not sure what the OP is asking in the first place. He says `I want it to return the number of rows.`

Comment: @Pekka that's easy. I'll explain. He is getting different types of arrays based on the number of rows returned. And trying to build his further logic on the number of array items.

Comment: @Pekka actually he can't count members this way. C'mon stop playing retard just to bite me :) The case is all clear.

Comment: +1 for consistently returning an array of rows.  For the haters, consider that each row is an array -- and if one row is returned (and not in an array), `count($ndata)` won't be 1 -- it will be *the number of columns in the row*.  Making it a lot trickier to tell whether `$ndata` is a row or an array of rows.